# Passing month name as parameter to crystal report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, parameter-passing

I am making a report where I have to show records by month, I used a drop down list with the names of months and another with a list of Years. I used the selection formula on the record:

```
{daily.date} >= cdate(year(currentdate),(Month ({?startdate})),1)
and
{daily.date} < dateserial(year(currentdate),(Month ({?startdate}))+1,1)
```

How can I pass the the name of month and the year as parameters to the report so that the report of that month & year can be viewed...
If I select january and 2012 then I should be able to view records of jan,2012 in my report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind, you will need to pass in the month name appropriate for the computer's current regional settings; passing in "March" may work where I am, but won't work in other countries.

For the month, you can create a parameter called `?MonthParam`, and add this to your Record Selection Formula:

```
MonthName (Month({YourTable.YourColumnName})) = {?MonthParam}
```

For the year, just do:

```
Year({YourTable.YourColumnName}) = {?YearParam}
```

Add it all together and you have:

```
MonthName (Month({YourTable.YourColumnName})) = {?MonthParam} AND
    Year({YourTable.YourColumnName}) = {?YearParam}
```